# Set different special color for each Font Awesome's icon with hover

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

i am getting a problem on hover, i want to give effects on hover for a single icon without affecting others

i am using

```css
.follow {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Rubik', serif;
}

.follow1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.icon i {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

.icon i:hover {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div class="follow">
  <p class="follow1">Follow Us on:</p>
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="color: rgb(11,134,238)"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram" style="color:rgb(193,50,158)"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter" style="color: rgb(29,161,242)"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g" style="color: rgb(221,77,66)"></i>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: are you trying to change colors?

Comment: hello dgknca can you tell me how can i add a video to my question for better understanding , you said can't give link through facebook, i am a new user in stack overflow

Comment: So remove the styles from the HTML, add them to your CSS file and then add the appropriate `hover` rule for each.

Comment: you can upload the video to a public platform. I couldn't see the video because I don't have a facebook account. but instead of adding videos, just write what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your icons with a span. And use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) to assign a special color for each.

```css
.follow {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Rubik', serif;
}

.follow1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.icon span {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-right: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: .2s;
}

.icon span:hover {
  color: var(--color);
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div class="follow">
  <p class="follow1">Follow Us on:</p>
  <div class="icon">
    <span style="--color: rgb(11,134,238)"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></span>
    <span style="--color: rgb(193,50,158)"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></span>
    <span style="--color: rgb(29,161,242)"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></span>
    <span style="--color: rgb(221,77,66)"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.follow {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Rubik', serif;
}

.follow1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.icon i {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-right: 45px;
}

 .fa-instagram:hover {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  display:inline-block;
}

.icon{
display:flex;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<div class="follow">
  <p class="follow1">Follow Us on:</p>
  <div class="icon">
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f" style="color: rgb(11,134,238)"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-instagram" style="color:rgb(193,50,158)"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-twitter" style="color: rgb(29,161,242)"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g" style="color: rgb(221,77,66)"></i>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Icon class put in every (i-tag class) before (fab) class